# laravel-echo-server not broadcasting events

Tags: laravel, websocket, socket.io, laravel-echo

I followed the documentation for configuring laravel-echo-server with redis as the broadcast driver.

I managed to join the channel I created but in the output of the command `DEBUG=* laravel-echo-server start` I get this:

```bsh
Server ready!

  engine intercepting request for path "/socket.io/" +0ms
  engine handling "GET" http request "/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MapZmuQ" +1ms
  engine handshaking client "qu2wNp4IrLre3oJeAAAA" +7ms
  engine:socket sending packet "open" ({"sid":"qu2wNp4IrLre3oJeAAAA","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}) +0ms
  engine:socket sending packet "message" (0) +1ms
  engine:polling setting request +0ms
  engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +1ms
  engine:polling writing "96:0{"sid":"qu2wNp4IrLre3oJeAAAA","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}2:40" +2ms
  engine:socket executing batch send callback +9ms
  socket.io:server incoming connection with id qu2wNp4IrLre3oJeAAAA +492ms
  socket.io:client connecting to namespace / +0ms
  socket.io:namespace adding socket to nsp / +0ms
  socket.io:socket socket connected - writing packet +0ms
  socket.io:socket joining room qu2wNp4IrLre3oJeAAAA +0ms
  socket.io:socket packet already sent in initial handshake +0ms
  socket.io:socket joined room qu2wNp4IrLre3oJeAAAA +1ms
  engine intercepting request for path "/socket.io/" +206ms
  engine handling "POST" http request "/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MapZm-U&sid=qu2wNp4IrLre3oJeAAAA" +1ms
  engine setting new request for existing client +0ms
  engine:polling received "121:42["subscribe",{"channel":"issueUpdates","auth":{"headers":{"X-CSRF-TOKEN":"GyZ4Z0igQp4gaMSiYgFrmXKOCsMX0zXnvOAxUZrr"}}}]" +193ms
  engine:socket packet +186ms
  socket.io-parser decoded 2["subscribe",{"channel":"issueUpdates","auth":{"headers":{"X-CSRF-TOKEN":"GyZ4Z0igQp4gaMSiYgFrmXKOCsMX0zXnvOAxUZrr"}}}] as {"type":2,"nsp":"/","data":["subscribe",{"channel":"issueUpdates","auth":{"headers":{"X-CSRF-TOKEN":"GyZ4Z0igQp4gaMSiYgFrmXKOCsMX0zXnvOAxUZrr"}}}]} +690ms
  socket.io:socket got packet {"type":2,"nsp":"/","data":["subscribe",{"channel":"issueUpdates","auth":{"headers":{"X-CSRF-TOKEN":"GyZ4Z0igQp4gaMSiYgFrmXKOCsMX0zXnvOAxUZrr"}}}]} +183ms
  socket.io:socket emitting event ["subscribe",{"channel":"issueUpdates","auth":{"headers":{"X-CSRF-TOKEN":"GyZ4Z0igQp4gaMSiYgFrmXKOCsMX0zXnvOAxUZrr"}}}] +0ms
  socket.io:socket dispatching an event ["subscribe",{"channel":"issueUpdates","auth":{"headers":{"X-CSRF-TOKEN":"GyZ4Z0igQp4gaMSiYgFrmXKOCsMX0zXnvOAxUZrr"}}}] +0ms
  socket.io:socket joining room issueUpdates +1ms
[10:03:27] - qu2wNp4IrLre3oJeAAAA joined channel: issueUpdates
  socket.io:socket joined room issueUpdates +6ms
  engine intercepting request for path "/socket.io/" +83ms
  engine handling "GET" http request "/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MapZm-U.0&sid=qu2wNp4IrLre3oJeAAAA" +0ms
  engine setting new request for existing client +1ms
  engine:polling setting request +83ms
  engine upgrading existing transport +67ms
  engine:socket might upgrade socket transport from "polling" to "websocket" +149ms
  engine:ws received "2probe" +0ms
  engine:ws writing "3probe" +1ms
  engine:socket writing a noop packet to polling for fast upgrade +170ms
  engine:polling writing "1:6" +238ms
  engine:ws received "5" +185ms
  engine:socket got upgrade packet - upgrading +83ms
  engine:polling closing +84ms
  engine:polling transport discarded - closing right away +0ms
  engine:ws received "2" +25s
  engine:socket packet +25s
  engine:socket got ping +0ms
  engine:socket sending packet "pong" (undefined) +0ms
  engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +0ms
  engine:ws writing "3" +1ms
```

I can see it receives pings and sends pongs, but I don't know why my
`event(new IssueCreated($issue))` Never go throw the channel and get broadcasted.

My front end code:

```
if (io !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('subscribing..');
    // Issue created code
    Echo.channel('issueUpdates')
        .listen('IssueCreated', (e) => {
            console.log('new issue');
            console.log(e);
        });
}
```

I get that I joined the room successfully, but when I fire the event, it doesn't show neither in my laravel-echo-server log or in my console.log

What can I do to debug? and please let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: Have you tried with the entiere classname : `.listen('.Namespace\\Event\\IssueCreated', ...)` ?

Comment: @JulienMetral just tried, nop not working. no errors, nothing appearing neither on the backend side nor on the front-end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, for whoever facing the same issue:

My problem was in the configuration of the Queue listener, I used supervisor to keep the process alive, and I didn't configure the command attribute properly with `php artisan queue:listen`

Bare in mind, you must have 2 things running at the same time, `laravel-echo-server start` and `php artisan queue:listen`

If you only ran `laravel-echo-server` and wondering why your events are not firing, follow [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#supervisor-configuration) to configure laravel queues.